# No matter what I do, this PHP function wont find the directory, why?

Tags: php

I have now spent several hours trying to figure this out.

I have this function to take an image on the server,copy it, resize it, and save it in a temporary location.

The function works and is tested inside another php file.
But THIS PHP FILE refuse to find the folder '../temp_images' (you can see it in the variable $temp_path).

I have tried all kinds of stuff, adding server root etc...

**Does anybody know why this function cant find the path to the directory in this php file, but it can in another php file in the same folder?**
The function I am referring to is at bottom of the code, `imagejpeg();`

Here is the function (shortened):

```
function show_pics($tot_pics, $id_string, $category){

        $ad_id_stripped = end( explode( '_', $id_string ) );
        $img_path="SV/main/ad_images/$category/";
        $temp_path="../temp_images/remove_images/";
        $maxH = 70;
        $maxW = 93;
        $top_offset = 0;
        for ($i=1; $i<=$tot_pics; $i++){

                     $image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($fwidth, $blank_height);
                     $white = imagecolorallocate($image_p, 255, 255, 255);
                     imagefill($image_p, 0, 0, $white);

                     $image = imagecreatefromjpeg('../ad_images/'.$category.'/'.$ad_id_stripped.'_'.$i.'.jpg');

                     imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, $top_offset, 0, 0, $fwidth, $fheight, $width_orig, $height_orig);

                     imagejpeg($image_p, $temp_path, 100);


        }}
```

Thanks

Comment: Well, you're not actually saving the image to the temp_path, maybe that's why you can't find them from there?

Comment: I forgot to add it to the text above, check the update... this is right now! temp_path instead of '../'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where is this PHP file located? And you don't use  $temp_path anywhere in your code? :)

https://www.php.net/imagejpeg the second parameter should be a filename, not a directory.

Comment: in a bincgi folder, and I forgot to write the temp_path variable in, check code again...

Comment: You are right... I looked in the description of the input variables on that same link, and there it says the input should be a path... Check it out, they are very confusing about that... Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

This function is used to display random image i.e. at header position of a site. It reads the whole directory and then randomly print the image. 
       I think it may be useful............